# ServletContext getRealPath method - what is a virtual path?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-container

I am reading the documentation for the [`getRealPath(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) and I became confused when I read this statement

> Returns a String containing the real path for a given virtual path. For example, the path `/index.html` returns the absolute file path on the server's filesystem would be served by a request for `http://host/contextPath/index.html`, where contextPath is the context path of this ServletContext..

What is a virtual path? let's say I am inside in my deployment environment and when I say getRealPath("index.html") does this usually points to the WEB-INF directory? or does getRealPath() starts reading the root directory(inside the folder name of the web app)?

Comment: so if we say root, it is "Web-Content" in eclipse?

Comment: Could you explain it in an answer or expound on it in. I wanted to select your comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServletContext.getRealPath(String s)` returns the real file system path. The input string is interpreted relative your Web Applications' Context Path.

In e.g. eclipse this is typically the folder `WebContent` inside your Web Application project (it is possible to customize that). After building a WAR file out of the project, you'll realize that the `WebContent` folder disappeared, so on the server the input string is interpreted relative to the WAR files' folder (or the .war library - this depends whether you explode the WAR during deployment or not).

**A note on security**

This method should (not must) only be used in case you want to access a file on the serverside. Typical scenario is parsing a configuration file during startup. Just keep in mind to never let the caller of your application know the real file system path of a given resource.

Answer (score 8):

The paths of resources you access from within the web container are all **virtual paths**. Their virtual root is the base folder of the web application. But in the actual **operating system** where they reside, they will be in a "concrete" location for sure. `getRealPath` gives you that path.

Say you have a jsp named *index.jsp*:

[image]

[image]

Take note that whenever you use this, you're creating cracks on the portability of your web application.