# find correct ablsolute path to app folder clojure/ring

Tags: clojure, glassfish, ring

I using clojure+ring for build web application running on Glassfish 3.
For correct initialization log4j i need find correct absolute path to WEB-INF folder.

Is the any way to determine absolute path to WEB-INF folder in web app running on app-server/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) method.

For example, insert the following into an XHTML:

```
Path: #{request.servletContext.getRealPath("/")}
```

This will show the full path to your XHTML file, e.g. when you insert this into a file called `index.xhtml`, it will show you the directory which contains this `index.xhtml`.

Because most of the time, the XHTML files are not placed in the `WEB-INF` folder, you may have to concat the strings in the following way:

```
#{request.servletContext.getRealPath("/")}WEB-INF
```

You can also do it in a handler:

```
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

    System.out.println("Path: " + request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
```

**See also:**

- [What does “/” mean in the method 'servletcontext.getRealPath'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-mean-in-the-method-servletcontext-getrealpath)
- [ServletContext getRealPath method - what is a virtual path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523848/servletcontext-getrealpath-method-what-is-a-virtual-path)
- [Retrieve the web app root path in JSF Managed Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377643/retreive-the-web-app-root-path-in-jsf-managed-bean)

Comment: Thanks for response. But in clojure i'am using ring init function and i don't know, how i can access to ServletContext var.